# ivysvn locked out of subversion if enter incorrect password

Tags: svn, authentication, ivy, resolver, lockout

I have  multiple dependencies in my ivy.xml and am using ivysvn passing in a username and password.

If the password is entered incorrectly, then since there are multiple dependencies, the auth fails multiple times and so I am now locked out of subversion.

Is there a way, that I can force it to check the resolver credentials first OR
to exit when the first dependency fails - so that I don't get the lockout?

```
<ivysettings>
<resolvers>
  <svn name="ivysvn" repositoryRoot="https://machine1/svn//Repository" 
     userName="${user.name}" userPassword="${svn.password}" >
  <artifact pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
  <artifact pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
 </svn>
</resolvers>
```